# Get domain name from IP address in Go

Tags: dns, go

I'm trying to resolve the host name from an IP address, which is apparently proving to be a little more challenging than I thought it'd be.

I've tried using a couple of functions, including the `net.LookupHost` method, but all of them seem to be just returning the IP address which I input.

Here's the code which I am using:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    // obtained from ping -c 1 stackoverflow.com, should print "stackoverflow.com"
    addr, err := net.LookupHost("198.252.206.16")
    fmt.Println(addr, err)
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    // obtained from ping -c 1 stackoverflow.com, should print "stackoverflow.com"
    addr, err := net.LookupAddr("198.252.206.16")
    fmt.Println(addr, err)
}
```

Output:

```
[stackoverflow.com.] <nil>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need [LookupAddr](http://tip.golang.org/pkg/net/#LookupAddr) instead of LookupHost.