# How to retrieve Connection-Specific DNS Suffix for Interface in Go?

Tags: windows, go, dns

I am on a windows machine and programming in Go. When I do an ipconfig I am able to see my machine's interfaces.

Whenever I execute net.InterfaceAddrs() I get a bunch of IP addresses, and I know which one is the one I am looking for, but I want to be able to tell if those addresses belong to my domain. In the output of ipconfig I can tell this by reading the Connection-Specific DNS Suffix entry which has my "company.com" listed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

See: [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512840/get-domain-name-from-ip-address-in-go)

try net.LookupAddr for each IP you get from net.InterfaceAddrs
assuming they reverse back correctly, they should end in your domain name.

Comment: This currently returns an empty array for me for the connection that lists "company.com" as a DNS suffix